# Beginner question: Collision is not working

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm a total beginner and just finished the famous donut tutorial.

Now I've started with my first own project and facing a problem that I cannot solve.

I modeled a light bulb and would like to fill it with stones. I've set up a rigid body system, but the stones are passing through the bottom of light bulb instead of staying in it.

I've made a simplified test then, where I just created some spheres and throw them into a  half cutted sphere (bowl). There it worked perfectly, but when I try the same with my stones and the light bulb it does not work.

Can the scaling of my models be a problem? The size of the stone is roughly 1cm... probably even less and the glass ~3mm. Can that be an issue?

[image]

Comment: The thickness of the glass, is it from a solidify or modeled? Either way, i would check the normals [Face Orientations](https://imgur.com/MasZWd0), it's just a different way to deal with based on the situation.

Comment: @Xylvier Thanks for you reply! 

The thickness is from a solidify modifier. I checked the face orientation and everything is Ok from what I see. 

However, I could solve the problem by reduce the falling speed (gravity) from 98 m/s to 1m/s. I'm not really sure why this solves the problem and still sometimes one of the stones pass through the glass, but at least most of them stay inside now.

I guess because of the small sizes the98 m/s were too fast.. or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment i would suggest the following solution:

1. Make a copy of the container object, adding a "-simhelper" at the end allows for easier identification later.
2. Select the copy and adjust the thickness of the solidify modifier to at least the size of the objects that are gonna fall in. **Explanation a bit below.**
3. Make the copy invisible in render by going in the **Object Properties**, under **Visibility** un-check the **Show in Renders** and in **Viewport Display** un-check the **Shadow** and maybe set the **Display As** to "Bounds".
   [image: Display settings]
   This way the simulation helper object will not bother you in the viewport or render.
4. Select the simhelper object and then the original, make sure the original is highlighted as yellow, active, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> "Object", making the simhelper a child of the original, in case you have to move the original later.
5. Now you can disable the "Rigid Body" on the original
6. Test the simulation and adjust the thickness of the solidify modifier as needed.

**Little Explanation:**
The Reason for using a thicker simulation helper is that the simulation uses sub-steps to catch an intersection, if the object falls to fast and passes through the walls without being caught by the simulation, it keeps falling and results in your problem situation.

Happy Blending